# Mapping Arturia's MiniLab Mk II to GarageBand

Tags: midi, midi-controller-keyboard, garage-band

I bought the **Arturia MiniLab Mk II** for my son's birthday next week. I wanted to prepare the mapping using Arturia's own **MIDI Control Center**. It kinda works, but I have trouble mapping (knob) controls to a certain channel. The knobs only control the currently selected channel, not the one defined in the mapping.

I attach a screenshot to show my settings. It shows that knob 2 is selected and should be mapped to channel 2. The CC number is 7 (Channel Volume).

Maybe someone can recommend a DAW controller that works better with GarageBand... Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell: Garageband doesn't support this type of mapping...